# Can't find symbol error when trying to use string from random value from a list

Tags: java, find, symbols

this is basically my first java program except for Hello world.
I've tried getting out as much errors as possible for the last hours, but I keep getting new ones. I try to Google solutions but in the end they end up giving me new errors, but I guess that's how u learn ^^

I'm stuck though, I get the following error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUUsb.png

I've tried a couple of different ways to achieve my goal, which is selecting a random string from the list lijstKaarten.
The whole goal of the program is that u pick a card by inputting which type (Hearts, clubs, diamonds, spades) and a card number. 
The computer has to also pick a card, my exercise tells me to use a default card but I'd rather generate a random type and number to show the computer's choice.

Here's my code:

```
package userinput;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Thuisopdracht {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        List<String> lijstKaarten = new LinkedList<String>();
        lijstKaarten.add("Harten");
        lijstKaarten.add("Ruitens");
        lijstKaarten.add("Klaveren");
        lijstKaarten.add("Schuppen");

    Random rand = new Random();
    while (true) {
        int computerKeuze = rand.nextInt(lijstKaarten.size());
        String stringcomputerKeuze;
        stringcomputerKeuze = lijstKaarten.get(computerKeuze);
    }


    double computerNummer = (Math.random() * (13 - 1)) + 1;

    String typeKaart;
    typeKaart = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Welk type kaart kies je?");

    InputStreamReader istream = new InputStreamReader(System.in) ;
    BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(istream) ;
    System.out.println("Welke kaartnummer kiest u? (1-13)");
    String kaartNummer = bufRead.readLine();

    int intKaartNummer = Integer.parseInt(kaartNummer);

    System.out.println("De computer koos " + stringcomputerKeuze + " " + computerNummer);
    System.out.println("Jij koos " + typeKaart + " " + kaartNummer);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `String stringcomputerKeuze;` is not initialized and declared inside the while loop. You cannot access it from the println you did. Initialize it and declare it outside the loop.

```
Random rand = new Random();
String stringcomputerKeuze = "";
while (true) {
        int computerKeuze = rand.nextInt(lijstKaarten.size());
        stringcomputerKeuze = lijstKaarten.get(computerKeuze);
}
```

You need also a stop condition in your loop cause it will run indefinitely.
You can add a counter per example :

```
        String stringcomputerKeuze = "";
        int counter = 0;
        while (counter != 5) {
            int computerKeuze = rand.nextInt(lijstKaarten.size());
            stringcomputerKeuze = lijstKaarten.get(computerKeuze);
            counter++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

With in the method you have to initialize the variables,before using them

you have not initialized

```
String stringcomputerKeuze;
```

try to initialize like

```
   String stringcomputerKeuze =null;
```

or

```
  String stringcomputerKeuze ="";
```

Answer (score 0):

A variable is only visible within the brackets it was declared in.

So, in the following code:

```
while (true) {
    int computerKeuze = rand.nextInt(lijstKaarten.size());
    String stringcomputerKeuze;
    stringcomputerKeuze = lijstKaarten.get(computerKeuze);
}
```

`stringcomputerKeuze` only exists within the brackets of the while, when you refer to it later, Java has no idea what you're talking about.

Move the declaration outside of the brackets.